# Configure Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 Failover Cluster from Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, cluster, failover, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

How do I configure Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 Failover cluster capabilities? Can I use mmc from a vista system or do I have to use Powershell?

Comment: I installed RSAT for Windows Vista, but when I try to activate the cluster on the Hyper-V Server machine it says that it only works with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise or Datacenter. I think I need a newer version of RSAT, but I can't find one.

Comment: Do you have access to the machines as administrator?

Comment: Yes, I own the domain admin account and I'm the machine admin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the RSAT tools for Windows 7:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

I ended up buying a Windows 7 licence...